# How to remove time from datetime in BiqQuery(LegacySQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

DATE_ADD((current_date()), -1, "DAY") as ReportRange2

Above returns the result as follows, where in, I would like to remove the time part and SQL to use the date alone.

[Date with Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va4Yi.png)

I want something like,

[Just date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1ylD.png)

Comment: A Standard SQL way would be `CAST(... AS DATE)`, don't know if it's working in BigQuery.

Answer (score 2):

for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  CURRENT_DATE() AS today, 
  DATE(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -1, "DAY")) AS yesterday
```

with result as below

```sql
today       yesterday    
----------  ----------
2017-07-27  2017-07-26
```

Meantime it is quite recommended to [`migrate your legacy sql to standard sql`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)
If you will - below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (with the same result of course)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CURRENT_DATE() AS today, 
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)) AS yesterday
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the date function so

```
DATE(DATE_ADD((current_date()), -1, "DAY")) as ReportRange2
```

In my experience that should work in Legacy SQL.

Also, if you haven't found it yet I use the [Legacy SQL Query Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#datetimefunctions) frequently for quick things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`cast`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#cast) this `datetime` value to a `date` value, to remove the time:

```
SELECT CAST( DATE_ADD((current_date()), -1, "DAY") AS date ) as ReportRange2
```